# React Native: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'props.navigation.navigate')

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I'm learning React Native and by trying to run this code using Expo it gives me the Exception error:
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'props.navigation.navigate'), at line 17 on App.js (marked in the comment)

There are two files: App.js and Untitled1.js

App:

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

  function App(props) {
    return (

      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.logo}>APPetito</Text>

        <Text style={styles.loginText}>Welcome to our app!</Text>
        <Text style={styles.loginText}>Choose what do you want to do</Text>

// [ THE FOLLOWING LINE CONTAINS THE ERROR ]
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("Untitled1")} style={styles.loginBtn}>

          <Text style={styles.loginText}>I eat food</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.loginBtn}>
          <Text style={styles.loginText}>I sell food</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

      </View>
    );

  }
// here there are the const styles
export default App;
```

Untitled.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, Text } from "react-native";
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/Entypo";
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

function Untitled1(props) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Icon name="check" style={styles.icon}></Icon>
      <Text style={styles.itWorks}>It works!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

// here there are the const styles
export default Untitled1;
```

What can I do to solve the problem?

Comment: try passing the props like this
`function App({ props })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you didn't create a Stack navigator in the first place to navigate between screens. Refer to react navigation docs to know more [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation)

According to the docs you have to implement the stack navigator such as:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

  function Home(props) {
    return (

      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.logo}>APPetito</Text>

        <Text style={styles.loginText}>Welcome to our app!</Text>
        <Text style={styles.loginText}>Choose what do you want to do</Text>

        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("Untitled1")} style={styles.loginBtn}>

          <Text style={styles.loginText}>I eat food</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.loginBtn}>
          <Text style={styles.loginText}>I sell food</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

      </View>
    );

  }


const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Untitled1" component={Untitled1} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I have updated your code a little bit to help you understand the concept.

Comment: Kindly mark the answer accepted if it solves your problem so that other people with same problem could use this answer